# How to limit number of parallel processes executed from C# program?

Tags: c#, concurrency, process

I need to create a code in C# that will execute a single process 1000 times (each time with different command line arguments), and I want to limit the number of processes that run in parallel to 4. In such a way so that all the rest will wait until at least one has finished, and then the next to start.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have couple options here

one is to use Parallel

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
  i =>
  {
    //do something
  });
```

another one is to use [Semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))

```
Semaphore pool = new Semaphore(0, 4);
```

You would call `pool.WaitOne()` before starting the worker and `pool.Release()` when your worker finishes

Or you might be able to limit the thread pool's size (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximum number of Threads in the ThreadPool to 4:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4);
```

Then you can queue up the 1000 processes in the ThreadPool:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(LaunchProcess));
        }
```

Here is the method that will run on the background thread and run your process. It uses WaitForExit() to ensure the process finishes before the thread will finish.

```
    static void LaunchProcess(object o)
    {
        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myprocess.exe");
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit(); // Critical to wait here for the process to finish
    }
```

That should limit the number of active processes to 4, I believe. Haven't tested.